# How to access to a file inside resource folder different from standard 'res' - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

In Android Studio, I need to use some resources (image, audio, etc...) from a folder different from the standard 'res',

Let's suppose that I have:

- the '_Resources' folder containing the image 'aaa.png' .
- the standard 'res' folder containing the image 'bbb.png'

I have put inside gradle file:

```
android {
   sourceSets {
         main.resources.srcDirs += 'C:/..../myLibrary/src/_Resources'
   }
}
```

After that I see in Android window (top left of Android Studio) correctly both the standard 'res' folder and the 'resources' folder.

if I have to access to 'bbb.png' of 'res' standard folder, I use:

```
import com.myproject.R
.....
int xxx = R.drawable.bbb
```

THE QUESTION IS:
how can access now to aaa.png?

It is not seen in R.  ; so I tried to import something else, but what?

Thank you in Advance
Fausto

Comment: Try changing `main.resources.srcDirs` to `main.res.srcDirs`, then see if you get `R` values generated for those resources.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: Any solution to this one? Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If you define two png file with the same name in multiple resource folders android will load just one of them (not sure which one).

The name of them are actually their ID. And the concept of ID is sensful if its unique. So you cant do this.

Having multiple resource folders is just something to separate files and make everything more clear and better. Just foldering and nothing more.

Comment: Thank you, but the name of the 2 files are different: aaa and bbb; the reason why I need a different resource folder, is because that folder is shared with other projects (in NetBeans).

Comment: If the files names are not the same there wouldnt be any problem. You don have to do anything to refer that other resource folder. Just add it to your resource folders and it will be added to your R file

Comment: You said in your question that currently both your res folders contain aaa.png !!!

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear, but the problem remains: how can I refer to the other resouce folder? I don't see 'aaa.png' in R.

Comment: Look just delete build folder of your project and clean and rebuild your project. Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: Dude i just did add two separate resource folder to my project as a test and im using it so easily. I dont know whats wrong with your project !!

Answer (score 0):

for those that could have the same problem:

I didn't have success in accessing to resource folder, but I found another solution that fits my needs:

I added the '_Resources' folder in Assets, writing in gradle file:

```
main.assets.srcDirs += 'C:/..../myLibrary/src/_Resources'
```

then I get access in code to resources by:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream myInputStream = assetManager.open("aaa.png");
```

That's all...

Answer (score 0):

I checked like 5 answers but there is no step by step guide. Hopefully this helps someone too.

1. Go into `build.gradle(:app)`
2. Inside the brackets, add this:

```
android {
   sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs += ['src/main/res', 'src/main/my_new_subfolder']
    }
}
```

The message `Gradle files have changed since last project sync` should appear. Hit `Sync now`

3. Right click on `src` of your project.

[image]

Create new `Android Resource Directory`

[image]

4. When the `New Resource Directory` opens, select drawable.

[image]

5. You should now be able to select your `Source set` with the same name inside your `build.gradle`
6. Click `Ok`, and now the new resource drawable subfolder should be created inside the directory:

`src -> main -> my_new_subfolder --> drawable`

You can now add drawables inside that folder and it can referenced in same way, if it were inside

`src --> main --> res --> drawable`

So if I had a `drawable` named `ic_country_usa` inside `my_new_subfolder --> drawable`

I reference it like so:

`int countryUsa = R.drawable.ic_country_usa`

Note:

If you have two drawables of the same file name in both the `res drawable` and `my_new_subfolder drawable`, it will only give reference to 1 drawable. So make sure to have different names.

Also I noticed you cannot see the `my_new_subfolder` unless you have `Project` selected rather than `Android`.

[image]